# Why is this Powershell argument getting corrupted when I run my powershell command?

Tags: powershell

When I run my powershell command, one of my arguments is getting corrupted with *another* arg value. Why? This looks so simple .. but it's not working :(

```
param (
  [switch]$help = $false,
  [string]$version,
  [string]$apiKey,
  [string]$source = $PSScriptRoot,
  [string]$destination = $PSScriptRoot,
  [string]$feedSource = "https://nuget.org",
  [string]$nuget,
  [switch]$clean = $false
)

function CleanUpInputArgs()
{
    Write-Host " **** " + $apiKey
}


CleanUpInputArgs
```

Busted Example: `$apiKey` should be null or empty. NOT `True`. => `& '.\foo.ps1' -version 123 -nuget aaaa -feedSource bbbb -clean True`

Correct Example: `$apiKey` displays `XXX`. => `& '.\foo.ps1' -version 123 -nuget aaaa -feedSource bbbb -clean True -apiKey XXX`

As a side note, when i'm using Windows Powershell ISE, the `-apiKey` arg option does *NOT* show in the autocomplete drop down box ... ??? Related?

Comment: In order to bind an explicit value to a switch parameter (such as `-clean`), you need `:`: `-Clean:$true` - otherwise, PowerShell will interpret your string `True` as a positional argument to whatever parameter it may match

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch types typically don't take any parameters so the `True` is getting passed to the next available parameter which is `-ApiKey`.

If you need to pass a value to a switch parameter it is done like so:

```
-Clean:$someBoolVariable
```

You specified `-Version` and the `-Help` parameter has a default value so the next available parameter is `-ApiKey`.

Comment: Wow - never knew that (obviously)! ta!

Comment: Also @keithhill -- how do I use switch statements in my arguments? or should i not do that? is there a better variable type for `true | false`, for args?

Comment: First, you don't need to initialize a switch parameter.  By default it is `not present` or $false if you test against it (unless someone specifies it e.g. -Clean).  If you are forwarding a switch value along from one function to another you can do this `-CleanInner:$clean` where both $CleanInner and $Clean are parameters of type switch.

Comment: So should I be using a switch statement here, though? and if so, does providing the cli argument `-Clean` basically mean: argument 'clean' is set to `true` ?

Comment: AH! i just tested this myself!!! so a `switch` means i don't need to pass a VALUE for the argument .. the argument DEFINES that it's true!!!! So i was mis-using the switch arg in TWO ways .. which caused this variable-corruption. AH! wow. assplosion by me :/

Comment: @Pure.Krome I would say just specifying the switch parameter `-Clean` with no argument defines it as $true.  But yeah, I think you've got it.  :-)